# jQuery - parallax - update background position correctly

Tags: jquery, scroll, window, parallax

### Goal

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293318/jquery-treat-multiple-instances-of-the-same-class-separately).

1. I'm trying to create a **parallax scrolling** effect.
2. The **parallax-container** are implemented like so:

   < div class="parallax slide-1" >< /div >

The parallax-effect successfully starts, when a container **is scrolled into view** and stops, when it **has left the view**.

### Problem

Unfortunately when I place a parallax-container further down on a page the effect starts with the **backgroundposition in the wrong place**.

I understand why this problem shows up, but am not sure how to solve it.

What I need is basically this:

1. Start the effect once a parallax-container is scrolled into view: **works**.
2. Stop the effect once it has left the view: **works**.
3. Only move the backgroundposition **by the distance scrolled since it has entered the view**. Not the distance scrolled relative to the top of the page.

[**Fiddle over here**](http://jsfiddle.net/pG5vy/3/)

For the parallax-container further down the page:

You can see the edges of the images. I'm trying to find a solution for that.

### Thoughts

So far my attempts where based around the idea to get the distance of a parallax-container to the top of the page only once (dont update it with each scroll) and implement it in the calculations.

But I cant seem to get it to work properly. Am I missing something?

Some further clarification:

1. There can be multiple parallax-container on any page.
2. Each can have their own background image set. (in the css)
3. I dont know how many parallax-container will be on a page.
4. I dont know where they are placed.
5. Only those that are visible move.

### Code

Only the relevant parts:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ // Bind window scroll event
    $( ".parallax" ).each(function() {
        if( $( this ).is_on_screen() ) { // Check if element is visible on screen after DOM loaded

            // ANIMATE PARALLAX EFFECT
            // If Parallax Element is scrolled into view do...

            // Variables
                var speed     = 2.5;
                var calc      = (-window.pageXOffset / speed) + "px " + (-window.pageYOffset / speed) + "px";
                var container = $( this );

            // Function
                container.css({backgroundPosition: calc});

        } else {
            // ...otherwise do nothing
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was actually going to put an edit on my old post, but since you made a new one, I'll add it here.

Seeing as you want to get granular with your parallax (ie. 2 are in view, but 1 has only moved 10px vs 30px), what you could do is store the speed option inside of your object, so that way, the speed movement will become independant. As so:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ // Bind window scroll event
    $( ".parallax" ).each(function() {
        if( $( this ).is_on_screen() ) { // Check if element is visible on screen after DOM loaded

            // ANIMATE PARALLAX EFFECT
            // If Parallax Element is scrolled into view do...
            // set a starting speed for each this:
            // $(this).speed = 2.5;
            //
            // Variables

                var calc      = (-window.pageXOffset / $(this).speed) + "px " + (-window.pageYOffset / $(this).speed) + "px";
                var container = $( this );

            // Function
                container.css({backgroundPosition: calc});

        } else {
            // ...otherwise do nothing
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: As discussed in the comments, to set the speed, try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $.fn.is_on_screen = function () {
        //..do your on screen stuff
    };
    $( ".parallax" ).each(function() {
       $(this).speed = 2.5;
    };
});
```

Comment: Hi Dylan, many thanks for reaching out again! Huge props.

As far as I understand your approach would require me to manually set a speed for each parallax-container I place on a page, right? I am looking for a solution where this is not neccessary. I've created [a fiddle over here](http://jsfiddle.net/pG5vy/3/) with the original code. Basically I want to get rid of the fact that you can see the image edges for parallax-container further down the page.

Comment: You could make a .each loop (like the one above) in your document.ready function, and set each speed...

Besides that, I wanna make sure i'm getting things right though. When you are scrolling around on the page, you want to make it so there is only one image to a page? or were you looking to have it so  you have both images, but only the most predominant one moves? or?

Comment: Ah interesting idea with the additional .each loops. I'll give it a try. For clarifications: There can be multiple parallax-container on any page. Each can have their own background image set. I dont know how many parallax-container will be in a page or where they are placed. Only those that are visible move. Thanks a lot for your help so far!

Comment: Not a problem. Thanks for the clarification. I will add an edit for the initial .each in just a sec

Comment: Hmmm... nope, I cant seem to be getting it to work :-( [Heres a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gw8FV/1/)